# Beginner Question - While loop for simple password program only looping question

Tags: c#, while-loop

I'm following a tutorial to create a simple command prompt program to ask for password (console.writeline) and write that the password is authenticated if inputted correctly (console.readline + if statement) - this runs smoothly:

```
Console.WriteLine("Please Input Your Password:");
var password = Console.ReadLine();
if (password == "secret")
Console.WriteLine("You have been authenticated");
else if (password != "secret")
Console.WriteLine("You have not been authenticated");
```

The next part of the exercise is to ask for the password to be typed again if it is incorrect. I followed the exercise per the tutorial but upon running the program the program loops the question line after line rather than methodically going through the steps of the code.

```
var password = "";
while (password !="secret")
Console.WriteLine("Please Input Your Password:");
password = Console.ReadLine();
if (password == "secret")
Console.WriteLine("You have been authenticated");
else if (password != "secret")
Console.WriteLine("You have not been authenticated");
```

Would be grateful for any advice! thanks!

Comment: Indend your code correctly and you'll know where your error come from. Hint : When you have more than 1 instructions in a `while` or `if` statement, you have to use curly brackets `{ }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `while` loop is missing curly blocks `{}`. when not specifing `{}` you the while loop only specifies to the next line instead of code block you wanted.

Also, you don't need the `else if (password != "secret")`. `else` is enough

```
var password = "";
while (password !="secret")
{
  Console.WriteLine("Please Input Your Password:");
  password = Console.ReadLine();
  if (password == "secret")
     Console.WriteLine("You have been authenticated");
  else
     Console.WriteLine("You have not been authenticated");
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Yet to learn this in the tutorial but very clear now!